# Draw them into the complex plane

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on the ReAnalysis problem. 
Let $z=(1+\sqrt3 i)/2$. Let $T \subset \mathbb{C}$ be the triangle with vertices $a=5,b=6+i,c=7.$ What geometric shape do $z^na, z^nb, z^nc$ form for any $n \in \mathbb{N}?$ Draw them into the complex plane together with $T$ and $z.$

I tried to use the polar form to find $z^n,$ which is $z^n=\cos(\pi/3)n + i \sin(\pi/3n)$, but I still can't figure out how to plot the product $z^na$ on the complex plane. [Complex plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34DVY.png). Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `I tried to use the polar form to find z^n` Look more carefully at $\,z^2\,$ and $\,z^3\,$, and remember that multiplying by $\,z^n\,$ means a rotation by $\,\arg z^n\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three points $5, 6+i, 7$ are vertices of a triangle.

As you mentioned $Z=e^{i\pi/3 }$ thus when you multiply a complex number by $z$, it rotates $60$ degrees counter  clock wise.

Thus the multiplication by $Z^n$ will rotate the triangle $n$ times $60$ degrees around the origin.

Note that the magnitude of points are unchained under this rotation.